# Python - Create a new file as soon as condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file

I am writing input entries from users into a file and I want to create a new file and continue writing the inputs into the new one as soon as there are 10 entries in the old file. For example, my original file has

```
1.something
2.
.
.
10. something
```

Then I want to create a new file and continue like this.
How can I do that? Help

Comment: After writing an item to the current file, increment a counter.  Check if the counter is equal to ten.  If it is, close the current file, open a new file, and reset the counter to zero.

Answer (score 0):

### First idea

If you execute it for each entry:

```
entries = 0
files = 0
def write(entry):
    global entries, files
    entries += 1
    if entries == 10:
        entries = 0
        files += 1
    with open("file-{}.txt".format(files), "a") as file:         
        file.write(entry + "\n") # \n is new line
```

Example of data:

```
for x in range(35):
    write(str(x))
```

### Another idea

If you have a list of all entries:

```
def write(entries):
    for i in range(0, len(entries), 10):        
        with open("file-{}.txt".format(i), "w") as file:        
            file.write("\n".join(entries[i:i + 10]))
```

Example of data:

```
write([str(x) for x in range(35)])
```

Obviously, there are better ways to archive this, for example (in my humble criteria) I would make a class for the first idea, so I can remove the `globals`, but you should develop them by yourself.